# React props intellisense with ASP .NET Core

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, react-props, react-proptypes

I am trying to get intellisense for React props. Before, I would pass in my ViewModel to Razor views (.cshtml). `@model namespace.WeatherVM`. Then I could easily have access to all available properties, like `@Model.TemperatureF`. Intellisense would popup and let me know what is available to access.

In React, I would like to do the same thing. In my VM, if I have like 40 properties, I need to have an intellisense or something that can show me all available properties.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
function renderForecastsTable(props) {
    return (
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                    <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {props.forecasts.map(forecast =>
                    <tr key={forecast.dateFormatted}>
                        <td>{forecast.dateFormatted}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.temperatureC}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.temperatureF}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.summary}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

How can I have intellisense tell me that props had forecasts? or tell me that each forecast has properties like temperatureF?

I've tried to work with proptypes with no luck.
**/models/weatherForecast.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export const WeatherForecast = PropTypes.shape({
    TemperatureC: React.PropTypes.string,
    TemperatureF: React.PropTypes.string,
    Summary: React.PropTypes.string,
    TestProp: React.PropTypes.string
});
```

Then trying to have intellisense work
**FetchData.js**

```
import * as Model from '../models/weatherForecast';
class FetchData extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.weatherForecast.TestProp // <---- No intellisense or no suggestion was provided for the existence of 'TestProp'. I had to manually write this in.
    }
}
FetchData.prototype = { weatherForecast: Model.WeatherForecast };
```

Any idea on what I can do regarding this? I know Typescript is one solution, but is that the only one?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you could make use of the [React PropTypes Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OfHumanBondage.react-proptypes-intellisense) extension.

This will then give you intellisense suggestions for your components with PropTypes.

Comment: I see, that's a start. Thanks for the suggestion. I been trying to use it with VS2017, but if I can't find any solution, I'll use VSCode instead.